# serverless function name declaration location or how to invoke java function via serverless

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, command-line-interface, serverless

Created project via command:

```
serverless create --template aws-java-maven --path hello-aws-lambda-java
```

deployed to aws via command:

```
serverless deploy
```

want to call function via command:

```
serverless invoke -f ${"name-of-function"}
```

Where do I find function name, if I try class name method name get error.

Answer (score 0):

function name is declared in serverless.yml file
functions:
${"name-of-function"}

Comment: If you answered your question yourself and satisfactory, consider marking it as the accepted answers. It makes it easier for others to see that no futher help is required by the community